# list.toArray(T[] a), what if the "T" is a "runtime type"?

Tags: java, list, generics, toarray

`list.toArray(T[] a)`, what if the `T` is a "runtime type"?

"`List`" interface in Java, the method: `T[] toArray(T[] a)`
OK, it's a quite old question, usually we use it like that:

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

My problem is, I don't know what the type "T" is when I was coding, the type "T" can only be decide in runtime,here is example:

```
List list=...;  // no generic type declared on this List
Class<?> clazz=...; //yeah, this is the real type of the element of the list, I can sure about that
```

Now I need to convert the list into an array which element type is clazz, what should I do?

May be you are wondering why do I have this kind of need:
I am making a little modification onto Morphia(It's a java-mongoDB framework). I need to aquire data from mongoDB and set it into right field of a POJO. In certain circumstance, the field type is array, the data aquired is a BasicDBList entity(which extends ArrayList),so the BasicDBList entity had to be convert into an array which type is compatible with the POJO filed.

I looked into source code of ArrayList, then achieved my goals with some ugly code:

```
List list=...;
Class<?> clazz=...;
Object targetArray=Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size());
list.toArray((Object[])targetArray);
```

Is there any better way to do this please?

Comment: Your solution is correct, `Array.newInstance()` is the way to go.

Comment: `list.toArray((Object[])targetArray);` gives you an `Object` array, right? So why not use the `toArray()` method without parameters (and assign the return value to `targetArray`)?

Comment: @arne.b `list.toArray((Object[])targetArray);` gives me an `Object array`, but I can do this: `clazz.cast()` after that because it's a 'clazz type array' inside. If I use `to Array()`, I'll get an `Object array`, and it can not be cast to any other array type. Have a try, please.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I did not think of that possibility (maybe because `BasicDBList` extends `ArrayList<Object>`, so I did not see how you would get anything other than an Object array out of it). But how do you get from the `Class<?>` object you have to that of the respective array class? (Btw: It is perfectly fine to write an answer to your own question if nothing better than your own solution comes up.)

Comment: @watchzerg: you should declare `targetArray` as `Object[] targetArray=(Object[])Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size());`

Comment: @arne.b actually,once i can sure about this field is `Class<?> type`,I just simply call `field.set(Object,Object);`, then jvm will do the right thing. I've thinked about do it manually,that's why I asked another question here: [get `String[].class` from `String.class`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392160/about-java-get-string-class-from-string-class-what-if-string-class-is/13392599)

Comment: @arne.b After I got `String[].class` from `String.class` in runtime, I can do this `clazz.cast(Object)` to convert it to it's actual type manually. Btw,thank you for reminding me about "answer to your own question", It's my first question on stackoverflow, thank you.

Comment: @user102008 yep,there is no so much difference, but your way is more standard. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @arne.b 's help in the comments, I think there is no better way to do this:

```
List list=...;
Class<?> clazz=...;
Object[] targetArray=(Object[])Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size());
Object[] myArray=list.toArray(targetArray);
```

Then I can set it to field without error:

```
Field field=...;    //ComponentType of this field can be sure is "clazz"
field.set(entity,myArray);
```

Or I can do this to convert it to it's actrual type manually:

```
Class<?> arrayClazz=Class.forName("[L"+clazz.getName()+";");
arrayClazz.cast(myArray);
```

Answer (score 5):

If your type is only known at runtime there is no solution here.

Java Generics are a compile time check and do not actually exist at runtime, it's called type erasure http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Meaning the runtime environment makes no such checks (for example, you can put Integers into a List generically typed as String  and using Object o = list.get(0) would run just fine)

The real point of generics is to provide compile time checks to prevent coding errors